# python: frequency count based on two array-rows in two columns (variables) in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I've seen some related questions with pd dataframe, but mine seems a bit specific. I believe my task should be solved with .groupby. Basically, I want to count a new value in a given column if it satisfies the criteria of appearing in another column as "A" AND "B" (cannot be just "A" or just "B" or "B" AND "C").

Input[]

```
Column -- Another_column
A -- word1
B -- word1
A -- word2
A -- word3
A -- word4
A -- word5
B -- word5
B -- word6
C -- word6
A -- word7
B -- word7

# I believe the code must be something related to the following, but adding some 
# criteria to be counted only when having "A" and "B" for a given "wordN": 
output = df.groupby('Another_column')[['Column']].nunique()
print(output)
print(len(output)):
```

Output[]

```
word1
word5
word7
3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the specific case of A&B, you can do something like this

```
(df.loc[lambda x: x['Column'].str.match("A|B")]
   .groupby("Another_column")
   .agg({"Column": "nunique"})
   .loc[lambda x: x['Column'] > 1])
```